# Use QuillJS directly in react without using react-quill

Tags: reactjs, quill

I was using ReactQuill package earlier in my production code but react-quill is not having a support on react 17.0 which is creating a bottleneck for our project, Now I want to use quill.js instead of react-quill but I'm stuck and couldn't find a good way to use quilljs directly in react project, any ideas on how to do this?